# Deleting Cookies from a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I set some cookie values in my form using jQuery. I can read them just fine in my Rails controller via the `cookies` method. When I call `cookies.delete(:my_key)`, they appear to be gone when I call `cookies` again. But when I reload the page, the cookies are back again.

Is there a way to delete the cookies for good from inside my controller?

EDIT

This is very strange since I'm looking at the response headers and they seem to be deleting the cookie. Maybe it's because it is a 302 request?

```
Set-Cookie: my_key=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For example, your cookie look like this

```
cookies[:foo] = {:value => 'bar', :domain => '.text.com'}
```

As you tried this one => `cookies.delete :foo`

The logs will say => `Cookie set: foo=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

Notice that the domain is missing. Tried this way

> cookies.delete :foo, :domain =>
>   '.text.com'

Function = >

```
# Removes the cookie on the client machine by setting the value to an empty string
# and setting its expiration date into the past.  Like []=, you can pass in an options
# hash to delete cookies with extra data such as a +path+.
def delete(name, options = {})
  options.stringify_keys!
  set_cookie(options.merge("name" => name.to_s, "value" => "", "expires" => Time.at(0)))
end
```

Comment: I seem to remember quite a few cookie related issues with Rack based frameworks. Your solution should work and hopefully any issues have cleared up since last year.

Comment: Gratuitous info that agrees with this answer: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html says "Please note that if you specify a :domain when setting a cookie, you must also specify the domain when deleting the cookie"

Answer (score 32):

According to the [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html), there is now a delete method, so if you have not set the domain use

```
cookies.delete :my_key
```

and if you have set the domain

```
cookies.delete :my_key, domain: 'mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the cookies by passing name and options to `delete` method as follows:

Syntax: `delete(name, options = {})`

Description: Removes the cookie on the client machine by setting the value to an empty string and the expiration date in the past. Like []=, you can pass in an options hash to delete cookies with extra data such as a :path.

Example:

```
cookies.delete('JWT', {
   value: "", 
   expires: 1.day.ago,
   path: '/api'
})
```